# Books on Politics

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, politics-government

Are there any books that provide a Jewish way of Politics? Anything that would possibly discuss types of governments, economic systems or what a politician should do would fit for what I am looking for. If possible, I would like something from the era of the Acharonim (but feel free to comment if their are earlier or later works). Perhaps the most preferable recommendation would be a book dedicated to the the topic, but if there is a book which has a section on the topic, that would also be of interest.

Comment: [Exodus 18:21-22](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0218.htm#21)

Comment: You might want to specify whether you want books from a particular era. Otherwise, the Torah, as @DoubleAA suggests, or Rambam Hilchot Melachim would seem to qualify, and I suspect that that's not what you're looking for. Also, please [edit] in more information about what would make a particular recommendation most valuable and why, to give us a basis for evaluating answers.

Comment: @IsaacMoses edited in.

Comment: There are hundreds, especially written in the current age.  But they all conflict

Comment: Ok, it probably won't be my accepted answer, but I'd be curious to see what works you speak of.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman care to list any??

Comment: @Bochur613 Someone else already has: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judaism_and_politics and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_political_movements

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman in the first link, it mentions that the Abarbanel was against monarchy. I clicked on the source at the bottom, but could not find that statement there. Do you know where that statement is by any chance?

Comment: And don't forget about http://smile.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=torah+political&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Atorah+political

Comment: @Bochur613 I'd ask the person who originally wrote that.

Comment: @Bochur613 The first Wikipedia link is meant to point to [this deprecated page](https://web.archive.org/web/20110821083739/http://www.schechter.org.il/iyounei_chabate.asp?id=238), which itself quotes the Abarbanel but gives no citation. Since there are so many books on the topic, maybe you would like to narrow down your specifications to get more satisfying answers.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Thank you for your kind example. I was sitting here wondering why the OP wanted to tell me how to look rather than what to look for.

Answer (score 4):

The Derashot Ha-Ran (no. 11) has a famous discussion of the two types of government in the Torah; in general the Abarbanel's commentary on Tanakh contains many important discussions of political ideas (for example, his discussion of monarchy in Devarim 17); [Simone Luzzatto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simone_Luzzatto), a 17th century Venetian rabbi, wrote a book defending the rights of the Jews of Venice; R. Samson Raphael Hirsch's commentary on the Chumash also contains many political insights.

More recently, R. Chaim Hirschensohn's Malki Ba-Kodesh contains discussions of democracy, women voting and being elected to office, and more ([I](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/1892),[II](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/10043),[III-IV](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/1544),[V-VI](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/3165)); R. Kook's [Mishpat Kohen](http://hebrewbooks.org/22302) contains a section of teshuvot on Hilkhot Melakhim;  R. Eliezer Waldenberg (known as the Tzitz Eliezer) wrote a book titled Hilkhot Medinah ([I](http://hebrewbooks.org/20799),[II](http://hebrewbooks.org/20825),[III](http://hebrewbooks.org/20880)) about issues involved in governing a society according to halakhah; similarly, the journal Ha-Torah ve-ha-Medinah contains many articles addressing these type of questions, as well as R. Shaul Yisraeli's [Amud Ha-Yemini](http://hebrewbooks.org/43775).

In addition, commentaries on the Rambam's Hilkhot Melakhim would be another good place to find relevant material; e.g., R. Yehuda Gershuni's [Mishpat ha-Melukhah](http://hebrewbooks.org/40624), and the (excellent) three-volume Be'er Miriam by R. David Yitzchak Man. Prof. Gerald (Ya'acov) Blidstein also wrote a very important work on this subject called עקרונות מדיניים במשנת הרמב"ם: עיונים במשנתו ההלכתית.

There is also an excellent four volume sefer by R. Naftali Tzvi Yehuda Bar Ilan titled Mishtar u-Medinah be-Yisrael al pi ha-Torah, which is available on Hebrewbooks.org: [I](http://hebrewbooks.org/53341), [II](http://hebrewbooks.org/53342), [III](http://hebrewbooks.org/53343), [IV](http://hebrewbooks.org/53344).

*The Jewish Political Tradition* is an anthology of Jewish texts from Chazal and rishonim relating to political issues. There are currently two volumes available, one on [*Authority*](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Jewish_Political_Tradition.html?id=PpAJ3NNxBYcC) and a second on [*Membership*](https://books.google.com/books?id=kcrV7aMBBhUC&source=gbs_navlinks_s).

Answer (score 1):

HaRav Avraham Yitzchak HaCohen Kook wrote a lot about judaism and politics in many of his articles. Let me know if you want more sources, but just as an example in "למהלך האידיאות בישראל", an article that was publishd at 1912 (and printed in "[Orot](http://www.hamadaf-y.co.il/%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A7-%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%95/%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A7/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA)"):

בְּרֵאשִׁית מַטָּעוֹ שֶׁל הָעָם הַזֶּה, אֲשֶׁר יָדַע לִקְרֹא בְּשֵׁם הָרַעְיוֹן הָאֱלֹהִי הַבָּרוּר וְהַטָּהוֹר בְּעֵת הַשִּׁלְטוֹן הַכַּבִּיר שֶׁל הָאֱלִילִיּוּת בְּטֻמְאָתָהּ-פְּרָאוּתָהּ, נִתְגַלְּתָה הַשְּׁאִיפָה לְהָקִים צִבּוּר אֱנוֹשִׁי גָּדוֹל אֲשֶׁר "יִשְׁמֹר אֶת דֶּרֶךְ ד' לַעֲשׂוֹת צְדָקָה וּמִשְׁפָּט" (1).
בניגוד לאומות העולם – אשר התאגדותם הלאומית מתחילה מקיבוץ חברתי לצרכים קיומיים ורק לאחר מכן מופיע ומתווסף הממד הנשמתי – "ישראל קדמו לעולם".(2) האידאל הישראלי קדם ליצירתו הממשית של העם.
בתחילת תהליך היצירה הממשי של עם ישראל עומד אבי האומה אברהם אבינו, שלמרות שחי בדור של עובדי עבודה זרה מלאי פראיות וברבריות, זיהה ודבק בבורא עולם ומנהיגו.(3) כבר אצל אברהם נתגלתה שאיפה פנימית להקים אומה גדולה שתאמין באחדות ה' ומתוך כך תבסס את מערכותיה השונות על אדני הצדק והמוסר. מתוך כך "אברהם מגייר את האנשים ושרה את הנשים".(4)
זוֹהִי הַשְּׁאִיפָה, שֶׁבָּאָה מִכֹּחַ הַהַכָּרָה הַבְּרוּרָה וְהָעַזָּה וְהַתְּבִיעָה הַמּוּסָרִית הַכּוֹלֶלֶת וְהָרָמָה, לְהוֹצִיא אֶת הָאֱנוֹשִׁיּוּת מִתַּחַת סֵבֶל נוֹרָא שֶׁל צָרוֹת רוּחָנִיּוֹת וְחָמְרִיּוֹת וְלַהֲבִיאֶנָּה לְחַיֵּי חֹפֶשׁ מְלֵאֵי הוֹד וָעֵדֶן, בְּאוֹר הָאִידֵיאָה הָאֱלֹהִית, וּלְהַצְלִיחַ בָּזֶה אֶת כָּל הָאָדָם כֻּלּוֹ. 
השאיפה להקים אומה שיודעת את ה' באה מכוח הבנה מבוררת ותביעה מוסרית פנימית שיש לרומם את כל האנושות כולה ולא להסתפק בתיקונם הרוחני של יחידים. יש ערך עליון לקשר את המציאות המוגבלת עם ההארה הנשמתית הרוחנית ולהופיע - במקום "חיים מלאי צרות רוחניות וחומריות"- חיים מלאי "הוד", אסתטיקה רוחנית, ו"עדן", עונג אלוהי, בקרב כל האנושות.
(1) בראשית יח יט
(2) מדרש תנחומא "נשא" יא
(3) הלכות עבודה זרה לרמב"ם פרק א
(4) רש"י בראשית יב ה

לְמִלּוּאָהּ שֶׁל שְׁאִיפָה זוֹ צָרִיךְ דַּוְקָא, שֶׁצִּבּוּר זֶה יִהְיֶה בַּעַל מְדִינָה **פּוֹלִיטִית** וְסוֹצְיאָלִית וְכִסֵּא מַמְלָכָה לְאֻמִּית, בְּרוּם הַתַּרְבּוּת הָאֱנוֹשִׁית, "עַם חָכָם וְנָבוֹן וְגוֹי גָּדוֹל", וְהָאִידֵיאָה הָאֱלֹהִית הַמֻּחְלֶטֶת מוֹשֶׁלֶת שָׁמָּה וּמְחַיָּה אֶת הָעָם וְאֶת הָאָרֶץ בִּמְאוֹר-חַיֶּיהָ. לְמַעַן דַּעַת, שֶׁלֹּא רַק יְחִידִים חֲכָמִים מְצֻיָּנִים, חֲסִידִים וּנְזִירִים וְאַנְשֵׁי-קֹדֶשׁ, חַיִּים בְּאוֹר הָאִידֵיאָה הָאֱלֹהִית, כִּי גַּם עַמִּים שְׁלֵמִים, מְתֻקָּנִים וּמְשֻׁכְלָלִים בְּכָל תִּקּוּנֵי הַתַּרְבּוּת וְהַיִּשּׁוּב הַמְּדִינִי; עַמִּים שְׁלֵמִים, הַכּוֹלְלִים בְּתוֹכָם אֶת כָּל הַשְּׂדֵרוֹת הָאֱנוֹשִׁיּוֹת הַשּׁוֹנוֹת, מִן רוּם הָאִינְטֶלִיגֶנְצְיָה הָאָמָּנוּתִית, הַפְּרוּשִׁית, הַמַּשְׂכֶּלֶת וְהַקְּדוֹשָׁה, עַד הַמַּעֲרָכוֹת הָרְחָבוֹת, הַסּוֹצְיָאלִיּוֹת, **הַפּוֹלִיטִיּוֹת** וְהָאֶקוֹנוֹמִיּוֹת, וְעַד הַפְּרוֹלֶטַרְיוֹן לְכָל פְּלַגּוֹתָיו, אֲפִלּוּ הַיּוֹתֵר נָמוּךְ וּמְגֻשָּׁם.
לְמִלּוּאָהּ שֶׁל שְׁאִיפָה זוֹ צָרִיךְ דַּוְקָא, שֶׁצִּבּוּר זֶה יִהְיֶה בַּעַל מְדִינָה פּוֹלִיטִית וְסוֹצְיאָלִית וְכִסֵּא מַמְלָכָה לְאֻמִּית, בְּרוּם הַתַּרְבּוּת הָאֱנוֹשִׁית, "עַם חָכָם וְנָבוֹן וְגוֹי גָּדוֹל",(1) וְהָאִידֵיאָה הָאֱלֹהִית הַמֻּחְלֶטֶת מוֹשֶׁלֶת שָׁמָּה וּמְחַיָּה אֶת הָעָם וְאֶת הָאָרֶץ בִּמְאוֹר-חַיֶּיהָ. 
כדי לממש את השאיפה האוניברסאלית הזו במלואה יש לבסס, בראש ובראשונה, אומה ייחודית שתשמש לעולם כ"לב". אומה זו צריכה להיות בעלת מערכות ציבוריות לאומיות וחברתיות משוכללות וחזקות היונקות את הכוח והחיוניות מהנטייה הרוחנית והאמונית, ומהשאיפה להתעלות לקרבת אלוהים.
לְמַעַן דַּעַת, שֶׁלֹּא רַק יְחִידִים חֲכָמִים מְצֻיָּנִים, חֲסִידִים וּנְזִירִים וְאַנְשֵׁי-קֹדֶשׁ, חַיִּים בְּאוֹר הָאִידֵיאָה הָאֱלֹהִית, כִּי גַּם עַמִּים שְׁלֵמִים, מְתֻקָּנִים וּמְשֻׁכְלָלִים בְּכָל תִּקּוּנֵי הַתַּרְבּוּת וְהַיִּשּׁוּב הַמְּדִינִי; עַמִּים שְׁלֵמִים, הַכּוֹלְלִים בְּתוֹכָם אֶת כָּל הַשְּׂדֵרוֹת הָאֱנוֹשִׁיּוֹת הַשּׁוֹנוֹת, מִן רוּם הָאִינְטֶלִיגֶנְצְיָה הָאָמָּנוּתִית, הַפְּרוּשִׁית, הַמַּשְׂכֶּלֶת וְהַקְּדוֹשָׁה, עַד הַמַּעֲרָכוֹת הָרְחָבוֹת, הַסּוֹצְיָאלִיּוֹת, **הַפּוֹלִיטִיּוֹת וְהָאֶקוֹנוֹמִיּוֹת**, וְעַד הַפְּרוֹלֶטַרְיוֹן לְכָל פְּלַגּוֹתָיו, אֲפִלּוּ הַיּוֹתֵר נָמוּךְ וּמְגֻשָּׁם. 
אומה כזו, בה מתאחדות האידאה האלוהית והאידאה הלאומית בשלמות, תברר לאנושות כולה, כי היכולת להתקשר ולהתחיות מהנטייה האמונית והרוחנית שייכת לא רק ליחידים מיוחדים אלא לכל שדרות החברה, מערכותיה ופרטיה; החל מהשכבה העליונה המשכילה ועד המעמד הנמוך. בכלל זה: בעלי "אינטליגנציה אמנותית", דהיינו כוחות ציור מופשטים,
"פרושים", כלומר אוחזים בהנהגות המתרחקות מגסות גופנית, ומעמד "הפרולטריון", מעמד הפועלים.

Comment: If you're looking for halakha, Rav Kook doesn't write as much as the Tzitz Eliezer, whose writings on the topic were collected and published under the title called

Comment: Called. . . called?!

Comment: @Matt Ping ^^^^

Comment: @WAF sorry I don't know how that happened. Called הלכות מדינה, vol. 1 available [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/20799)

Comment: oh, I realized based on your answer that you've figured it out, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Here some titles you might be interested:

1. [עקרונות מדיניים במשנת הרמב"ם - עיונים במשנתו ההלכתית](http://www.biupress.co.il/website/index.asp?id=562) by Gerald (Yacov) Blistein (Bar Illan, 2001)
2. [There Shall Be No Needy: Pursuing Social Justice through Jewish Law and Tradition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1580234259) by Rabbi Jill Jacobs (Jewish Lights, 2010)
3. [Covenant and Polity in Biblical Israel Biblical Foundations and Jewish Expressions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0765804522) by Daniel J. Elazar (Transaction Publishers, 1998)

Answer (score 1):

[Medieval Political Philosophy: A Sourcebook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/080147681X) provides extracts from the works of Saadyah Gaon, Judah Halevi, Maimonides, Isaac ibn Polgar, and Abravanel.